# interactive/visual merge tool for console?

Tags: linux, console, diff, merge

I'm a big fan of `meld` - a visual diff and merge tool for Gnome. It shows two files (or directories) side-by-side and with their differences highlighted, and I can easily select which parts I want to move from one file to the other.

I'm looking for a similar tool, but it should work on the (Linux) console, eg. it should not require any X server. Maybe using an ncurses interface.

Is there such tool?

Comment: See also (same Q on Stack Overflow): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991248/any-visual-diff-in-linux-console.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ah just found out about vimdiff. It pretty much does what I was looking for. here's a [quick guide](http://www.debianadmin.com/vimdiff-edit-two-or-three-versions-of-a-file-with-vim-and-show-differences.html)

Comment: @How to merge/copy changes from on file to another using vimdiff or vim -d

Answer (score 9):

You can use `vim -d file1 file2` for that.

Answer (score 8):

`sdiff`, a classic command line tool which shows text file differences side by side, also has an interactive merge mode. Use it by running

```
$ sdiff -o output.txt input1.txt input2.txt
```

It is the default interactive command line merge tool used by Gentoo Linux' [etc-update](https://dev.gentoo.org/~zmedico/portage/doc/man/etc-update.1.html) utility.

Advantages over `vimdiff` are ubiquitous availability and much simpler handling.

Comment: Easy to use, just press `1` or `2` to choose the wanted version. However, columns are truncated to only show 60 charcartes, and changes must be saved to a third file.

Comment: `sdiff` doesn't seem to have any coloring or highlighting options to highlight differences. This makes it very rudimentary and difficult to use.

Comment: @GabrielStaples I did not advertise anything else. It does basic highlighting of common and changed lines, though.

Comment: @fbmd, `sdiff file1.h file2.h` doesn't show _any_ color for me whatsoever. How do you get it to show color? it shows various `|` chars in the middle indicating contents on left and right are the same, and `<` and `>` chars showing left and right are different, but it has no color whatsoever. `sdiff --version` shows this version: `sdiff (GNU diffutils) 3.6`.

Comment: @GabrielStaples That's what I meant by highlighting. Not all terminals support color under all circumstances, so that is one of the most portable ways to highlight differences.

Comment: Nice. In interactive mode: `h` for help. I find `ed` to be most useful: edit both (decorated with a header).

Answer (score 7):

I use the **Midnight Commander** for this. Select a file on the left pane and another on the right, press `F9`, then Command > Compare Files.

It can also be called using the `mcdiff` command

Use `Enter` to navigate to the next diff, `F5` to merge the selected diff from the right to the left and `F15` (or `Shift + F5`) from left to right.

It is possible to change the keybindings (useful on Mac):

On `mc.keymap` file section `[diffviewer]` change from:

```
MergeOther = f15
```

To:

```
MergeOther = f6
```

If you want `F6` to be the default key for this, ask [here](https://midnight-commander.org/ticket/4163)

More info on `F1`

Comment: Actually, it does support merging to the right: `F15` (or `Shift`+`F5`).

Comment: Also, you can modify files during merging using `F4` (of `F14`, `Shift`+`F4` for the right pane). It will open partially merged file for editing in the position of last merge. So you can change what you want, save changes and exit from edit mode and it will return back to `mcdiff` to continue merging with updated file.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Updated